Is there a relation between minimum mean square error (MMSE) and Heavy tail distribution?
The requirement is to estimate the data samples ($u$) from the observed values ($v$) in the presence of additive white Gaussian noise $(n)$ (statistical characterization is available) , where the minimum mean square estimated value:
$$\hat{u}_\text{MMSE}=f(v,n),\text{e.g.} v=au+n$$
where $u$ is a random quantity which is generated and modelled using a probability density function (PDF) whose parameters values are known to us.
Note that the problem is quite common in communication engineering where from the received signal $v$, one needs to estimate a fading coefficient $u$, given the statistical characterizations of both $u$ and $n$ are known. For the time being $a$ is assumed to be known and is a constant non random quantity.
I believe that if the tail probabilities for a given distribution are changed by changing the parameter values. Then, higher tail probabilities of $u$ should lead to worsening of the MMSE between $u$ and $\hat{u}$.
Is my intuition correct? Is there some literature supporting the claim?

Can you clarify what "random data" means here? Why are these "u" values random data? Aren't the v's your data? Normally 'estimate' would relate to some population parameter. I'm unclear what the circumstances are.

@Glen_b I have corrected the description. $u$ are random data samples generated using a given PDF whose parameters are known.

Again, I am slightly puzzled by the use of the word data in relation to quantities that don't appear to be ... well data in the usual sense of the word in statistics. It seems you have a set of (unobserved) quantities $u_i$, $i=1,2,...,n$, generated from a process with fully specified  distribution, to which are added (? or perhaps not necessarily added? It's not 100% clear there) Gaussian noise $n_i$, which then produce the observations $v_i$. Is that correct? (Those $v$'s, following what I believe is pretty conventional usage, are what I would have called the data)

The term is less important than being completely clear about the fact that the $u$'s are unobserved and the $v$'s are observed, though.  It would be important to be as clear as possible about how the noise term enters the process. While you say the noise is additive, the way you wrote $f(u,n)$ implies something more general. If $n$ can only enter in a purely additive way, would you not write $v_i = f(u_i) + n_i$ instead? Or is the intent there that $f$ operates on a vector of $\mathbf{u}$ values to produce a vector of $\mathbf{v}$ values? So $\mathbf{v}=f(\mathbf{u}) + \mathbf{n}$?
